# How can I get managed threads from Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I can get a list of running threads from Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads, but I need to know the managed name of threads started with Thread.Start. It isn't a property on the ProcessThread object though. Is there a way to get this information from a ProcessThread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While CLR spawns an OS thread for each managed thread, it's not forced to. I mean, no standard guarantees that there should be a one to one mapping between OS threads and managed threads.

To quote MSDN:

> An operating-system ThreadId has no
>   fixed relationship to a managed
>   thread, because an unmanaged host can
>   control the relationship between
>   managed and unmanaged threads.
>   Specifically, a sophisticated host can
>   use the CLR Hosting API to schedule
>   many managed threads against the same
>   operating system thread, or to move a
>   managed thread between different
>   operating system threads.